# Using fgetcsv and fopen issue with looping never exiting

Tags: php, csv, while-loop

There's an issue with this piece of code it never gets to the "Done" echo.

```
 for($current_day=1;$current_day<=10;$current_day++){
    echo("lists/Day ".$current_day.".csv </br>");   
    $person_data = "";
    if ( ( $handle = fopen( "lists/Day ".$current_day.".csv", "r" ) ) !== FALSE ) {
        while ( ( $data = fgetcsv( $handle, 1000, ",", "//" ) ) !== FALSE ) {

            if ( $data[2]!="Grade" ) {
                $collection = $db->students;
                $person_data['last_name']  = trim( $data[0] );
                $person_data['first_name'] = trim( $data[1] );
                $person_data['fullname']  = $person_data['first_name'].' '.$person_data['last_name'];
                //var_dump($person_data);
                $cursor = $collection->findOne(array('fullname'=>$person_data['first_name'].' '.$person_data['last_name']));
                if($cursor!=null){
                    echo("UPDATE");
                    if($cursor['frees'][$current_day-1] != 1){
                        $cursor['frees'][$current_day-1] = 1;
                        echo 'Updated: '.$data[0] . " - ". $data[1] . " - ". $data[2] . "</br>" ;
                        $collection->save($cursor);
                    }   
                }
                else{
                    echo("ADD");
                    //addperson($data,$current_day);
                }

            }

            // do something with the data here
            //echo $data[0] . " - ". $data[1] . " - ". $data[2] . "</br>" ;
        }
        fclose( $handle );
        echo("Done");

    }
    else{
        echo "FALSE";

    }
}
```

outputs

```
    1
lists/Day 1.csv 
ADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADDADD
```

Which is correct but never loops to the second csv

Comment: What is "addperson" method doing? Is script timeouting or showing any error? "Update" / "Add" messages are shown?

Comment: Does the first `if` statement fail? If not, what error is PHP logging? We need more information!

Comment: The first if statement _does not_ fail. In fact it adds all the people up to the point but it never loops around for the second. I have updated code above to clarify. I also commented out the addperson to show that that is not the cause.